# Two template functions for two standard types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write two template functions. They must simply return reference to local variable. But it doesn't work:

```
class Cube_cache_value {
public:
  //...
  template<>
  QVector<unsigned short>& get_buffer<unsigned short>() { return vector; } // error here

  template<>
  QVector<float>& get_buffer<float>() { return float_vector; }

private:
  QVector<unsigned short> vector;
  QVector<float> float_vector;
};
```

> error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class hsp::Cube_cache_value'

Then I've tried to get functions out of class scope, but compiler still don't like it:

```
class Cube_cache_value {
public:
  //...
  inline QVector<unsigned short>& get_buffer() { return vector; }
  inline QVector<float>& get_float_buffer() { return float_vector; }

private:
  QVector<unsigned short> vector;
  QVector<float> float_vector;
};

template<>
QVector<unsigned short>& get_buffer<unsigned short>(Cube_cache_value* v) { //error here
  return v->get_buffer();
}

template<>
QVector<float>& get_buffer<float>(Cube_cache_value* v) { return v->get_float_buffer(); }
```

> error: expected initializer before '<' token

Please correct my code.

Comment: You do not want to specialize functions, but override them. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: You're returning those by non-const pointer, might as well just make them public and drop silly accessors.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, I need them to be template functions, because I want to use them in another template function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bad design in the first place. Why is your class storing 2 distinct vectors for 2 possible types? It's a bloat and you'd need to do this for any other type you might want.

Why not do this ?

```
template <typename T>
class Cube_cache_value {
public:
  // ...
  QVector<T>& get_buffer() { return buf; } 

private:
  QVector<T> buf;
};
```

Comment: I agree. I thought I can just add two functions and re-factor this class later. But I see it's much better to change it now.